# What is the additional functionality provided by transaction that isnt already provided by SaveChanges?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework, when I make changes to multiple models and at the end call `SaveChanges`, either all changes get stored into the database, or no changes get stored if any of them result in an error.

So this implicitly works like a transaction. So what exactly is the purpose of creating explicit transactions?

Comment: The additional functionality provided by transaction is that it allows you to rollback changes if there is an error. It provides more control over db transactions.

Comment: But SaveChanges doesn't protect against this if one of the preceding insert/update fails?

Comment: I think a transaction is useful to protect multiple SaveChanges? And also for cross context

Comment: Yes, you are right. In most cases SaveChanges or SaveChangesAsync is sufficient and this is default behaviour but when in some cases we need to use multiple SaveChanges  in single transaction then we use explicit transaction.